# After hitting Postman API Getting Params empty value as empty in controller by using webflex

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-restcontroller

**find postman snapshot**
[image]
**Below is my controller i'm using @WebfluxService Want to pass key value pair request from the postman while debugging i'm getting empty Value for params**

> below logger printing null value in my consol.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/bserviceobligation",consumes = { "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
public Mono<SyncBatchResponse> handleSyncBatch(@Valid @RequestParam Map<String, String> params,
        @RequestHeader(value = HEADER_APPLICATION_KEY, required = true) String appKey,
        @RequestHeader(value = HEADER_APPLICATION_ID, required = true) String appId,
        @RequestHeader(value = CORRELATION_ID, required = false) String correlationId) {
    LogHelper.info(this,"Calling SyncBatch for correlationId : "+correlationId);
    LogHelper.info(this,"Requested Value1 (" + params.get("Value1") + ')');
    LogHelper.info(this,"Requested Value0 (" + params.get("Value0") + ')');
    LogHelper.info(this,"Requested Value (" + params.size() + ')');
    String unitOfWorkId = null;

    if (correlationId != null && !correlationId.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {         
        if(correlationId.contains(",")){
            correlationId = correlationId.substring(1,correlationId.length());
        }           
        unitOfWorkId = correlationId;
    }else
        unitOfWorkId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    LogHelper.info(this,"unitOfWorkId: " + unitOfWorkId);
    boolean isValid = ldapService.checkAuthorization(appId, groupSBSOBLIGATIONHPIACCESS0);
    if (isValid) {
        LogHelper.info(this,"Application authorization against: Enterprise Directory (SUCCESS) (" + appId + ')');
        SyncBatchResponse response = syncService.prepareCombineOrchaRequest(params, appId,appKey, unitOfWorkId);
 return Mono.just(response);
    } else {
        LogHelper.info(this,"Application authorization against: Enterprise Directory (FAILURE) (" + appId + ')');
        SyncBatchResponse response = new SyncBatchResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(LDAP_STATUS_CODE);
        response.setStatusDescription(LDAP_STATUS_DESCRIPTION);
        return Mono.just(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For recent releases of WebFlux, `@RequestParam` does not bind the form-data or Key Value pair. In this case use `ServerWebExchange` instead.

For Minimal Example:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/api/query/ask", consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
    public Mono<String> handleSyncBatch(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
        return serverWebExchange.getFormData()
                .flatMap(data -> response(data));
    }

    private Mono<? extends String> response(MultiValueMap<String, String> data) {
        log.info("{}", data);
        return Mono.just("Success");
    }
```

This logs the key value pair sent from postman. The sample cURL:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:10120/api/query/ask' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'val1=asdafasdfasfd' \
--data-urlencode 'val2=["something","som1"]' \
--data-urlencode 'val3={"name":"abc"}' \
--data-urlencode 'val4=[{"name":"xc"},{"age":23}]'
```

More study: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20738

Comment: Then How to pass headers ::  @RequestHeader(value = HEADER_APPLICATION_KEY, required = true) String appKey,
   @RequestHeader(value = HEADER_APPLICATION_ID, required = true) String appId,
   @RequestHeader(value = CORRELATION_ID, required = false) String correlationId

Comment: you should get the headers from @RequeatHeader annotation